# Setting a model attribute to some sql value in Django

Tags: django

I have a model called job and I want to set a datetime attribute (started_time) to MySQL `now()` value. how can I do that in Django?

**I don't want to use the model `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` methods, since I have other applications who share the same DB and I don't want to handle timezones, thus I want to delegate that to MySQL**

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `auto_now`/`auto_add_now`, they are problematic. Instead, do this:

```
  started_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
```

-- assuming that you're working with timestamps in UTC.

Comment: Can you expand on how they are problematic?

Comment: Google for "auto_add and auto_add_now in admin fieldsets". Also, they use datetime.now() which is dependent on os timezone settings. You might say that those are features - not issues, but for me the less magic the better.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL trigger.